# SQLite Inner Join seems to produce duplicate rows and possibly discards some other rows

Tags: sqlite, join

I have some data about shops that looks something like:

[image: have]

where the unimportant data is omitted.

I have an existing SQLite query:

```
select s.COMSERNO, s.COMNAME, COMALTNAME, s.COMCODE, s.COMADDR, s.COMPCODE, s.COMCITY, x.lastVisit, y.memoText, l.COMCALL 

from TCOMPANY s 

left outer join ( select COMSERNO, max(CALEDATE || CALESTART) as lastVisit from TCALENTR where SALMSERN='000000000000019' and (CALEDATE || CALESTART) < strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', 'now', 'localtime') group by COMSERNO) x on (x.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join ( select MEMOSERN1 as comSerno, max(MEMOTEXT) as memoText from TMEMO where MEMOTYPE='0' and 0<length(MEMOTEXT) and MEMOSERN2 in ('Notes')group by MEMOSERN1) y on (y.comSerno=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join LSALCOM l on l.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO 

and SALMSERN='000000000000019' 

order by s.COMNAME, s.COMSERNO
```

The above returns 174 rows.

I want to show the 'Chain' for a shop, if it has one, so the data should look something like this:

[image: want]

I have another table, `LCOMCOM` and for each `COMSERNO` in my original result set (each shop) I need to determine if this shop is part of a chain and if it is, display that chain.

I join `LCOMCOM`  on `COMSERN2`, and if the column `LCOMATR1` has the value 'Chain' then it means the store `COMSERN2` is a chain.  I then take `COMSERN1` from `LCOMCOM` and use the original table, `TCOMPANY` to look up and show the Chain name.  Here is my code

`case when z.lcomatr1 = 'Chain' then  (select p.COMNAME from TCOMPANY p inner join LCOMCOM q on (p.COMSERNO=q.COMSERN2) where q.COMSERN1 = z.comsern1) else '' end as Chain`

Here is the `LCOMCOM` join:

`inner join LCOMCOM z on (s.COMSERNO=z.COMSERN2)`

I tried adding the above two pieces into my query but it doesn't do what I expected:

```
select s.COMSERNO, s.COMNAME, COMALTNAME, s.COMCODE, s.COMADDR, s.COMPCODE, s.COMCITY, x.lastVisit, y.memoText, l.COMCALL,

case when z.lcomatr1 = 'Chain' then  (select p.COMNAME from TCOMPANY p inner join LCOMCOM q on (p.COMSERNO=q.COMSERN2) where q.COMSERN1 = z.comsern1) else '' end as Chain  

from TCOMPANY s 

left outer join ( select COMSERNO, max(CALEDATE || CALESTART) as lastVisit from TCALENTR where SALMSERN='000000000000019' and (CALEDATE || CALESTART) < strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', 'now', 'localtime') group by COMSERNO) x on (x.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join ( select MEMOSERN1 as comSerno, max(MEMOTEXT) as memoText from TMEMO where MEMOTYPE='0' and 0<length(MEMOTEXT) and MEMOSERN2 in ('Notes')group by MEMOSERN1) y on (y.comSerno=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join LSALCOM l on l.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO 

inner join LCOMCOM z on (s.COMSERNO=z.COMSERN2)

and SALMSERN='000000000000019' 

order by s.COMNAME, s.COMSERNO
```

The above returns 548 rows, not 174. Some shops are now in 4 rows, like so:

[image: 4 rows]

And some shops are now in 2 rows, like so:

[image]

Adding `DISTINCT` after the initial `SELECT` reduces the row count to 348 and it now looks like all the Chain stores are in 2 rows.

I'm not sure what's going on here but presumably referring to `TCOMPANY` twice in both the `SELECT`s is wrong.  Can anybody tell me how to get 174 rows, with the chain, if appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CASE` statement wasn't needed and the `INNER JOIN` was moved into the bracketed `SELECT`:

```
select DISTINCT s.COMSERNO, s.COMNAME, COMALTNAME, s.COMCODE, s.COMADDR, s.COMPCODE, s.COMCITY, x.lastVisit, y.memoText, l.COMCALL,

(select p.comname from LCOMCOM q inner join TCOMPANY p on (p.COMSERNO=q.COMSERN1) where q.COMSERN2 = s.comserno and q.lcomatr1 = 'Chain') as Chain

from TCOMPANY s 

left outer join ( select COMSERNO, max(CALEDATE || CALESTART) as lastVisit from TCALENTR where SALMSERN='000000000000019' and (CALEDATE || CALESTART) < strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', 'now', 'localtime') group by COMSERNO) x on (x.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join ( select MEMOSERN1 as comSerno, max(MEMOTEXT) as memoText from TMEMO where MEMOTYPE='0' and 0<length(MEMOTEXT) and MEMOSERN2 in ('Notes')group by MEMOSERN1) y on (y.comSerno=s.COMSERNO) 

left outer join LSALCOM l on l.COMSERNO=s.COMSERNO 

and SALMSERN='000000000000019' 

order by s.COMNAME, s.COMSERNO
```